# Website text appearing only on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, web, font-face

I'm facing a strange issue on the text rendering of a website I have developed. When loading the page, some of the text doesn't appear until I hover over it; some not even then.

I am using font-face. If I reload the page, it works fine. If I empty the cache, the problem comes back. Frontend design is developed using bootstrap 2.3.2.

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML, otherwise we can't see what's gone wrong.

Comment: Without your code there is not much we can do.

Comment: the website is [link](http://www.noventacase.it/)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Chrome?

This may be due to a recent Chrome bug:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

Looks like they're working on a fix.

I'm using this as a temporary fix:

```
$(function() {
    // temporary fix for chrome font bug
    $('*').css('zoom', '1').css('zoom', '');
});
```

The idea is that it will trigger a redraw of all elements.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin My account is new, so I can't make a comment on the OP's question until I have 50 reputation. I've added a temporary fix that solved the issue for me for now.

Comment: Fair enough, -1 removed.

Comment: this solution does not work. Use this one instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text

Answer (score 0):

As said in the bug forum :
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

It's related to @font-face
just try to use arial or something instead your @font-face font and this should work.

Answer (score -1):

Remove font-face and re try. May be your text color is same color as your background color?
Hover color is different or something? Can you show your code or a link to a site?